# Lamport’s (Physical) Clock Synchronization Algorithm

Tags: messaging, distributed, clock, timing, distributed-system

As it's such a famous computer science paper, I decided to read Lamport's [Time, Clocks, and the Ordering of Events in a Distributed System](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/time-clocks.pdf). Besides his often-cited remarks on logical clocks, he also proposes an algorithm for synchronizing physical clocks (starting on page 562). I think I get the idea of that algorithm, however, on page 563, he lists two implementation rules that every process has to follow. I just can't seem to figure out what IR1 is supposed to mean:

> IR 1'. For each i, if Pi does not receive a message at physical time t, then Ci is differentiable at t and dCi(t)/dt > 0.

What does he mean with "Ci is differentiable"? Differentiable from what? And why does dCi(t)/dt have to be greater than 0? Don't we try to get it as close to 0 as possible after all?

Maybe this is a really dumb question that comes with a really obvious answer, but as of now I can't figure it out. So, help is much appreciated...

Comment: The term *differentiable* doesn't mean *"can be distinguished from something else"*. It is the calculus term, for the derivative of an algebraic function.

Comment: Haha, that makes a lot more sense. Language got me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this is saying, is that `Ci(t)` is a mathematically differentiable function of `t`; that is, the derivative of `Ci(t)` exists at `t`.  (AKA the value of `Ci(t)` is changing by some measurable amount at `t`)

`dCi(t)/dt > 0` just means that the derivative of `Ci(t)` is greater than zero. (AKA The rate at which `Ci(t)` changes is positive at `t`)

This is just a definition of `Ci(t)` as a function whose value increases whenever `Pi` does not receive a message.